# C++ classes uses each other

Tags: c++, inheritance, header-files

Sometimes during class designing I have an issue with class organization. For example I have an `Shape` class that is abstract base class for all type of shapes: rectangles, polygons, circles, etc:

`Shape.h`:

```
#pragma 

class Rectangle;

class Shape {
    public:
        Shape();
        ...

        virtual Rectangle boundingRectangle() const = 0;
};
```

And I have an `Rectangle` class derived from `Shape`:

`Rectangle.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include "Shape.h"

class Rectangle : public Shape {
    public:
        Rectangle();
        ...

        Rectangle boundingRectangle() const;
};
```

The obvious problem using such method is that I can't forward declare `Rectangle` in `Shape.h`. The only solution I know is to declare `Rectangle` right after `Shape` in `Shape.h` and in `Rectangle.h` include `Shape.h` (for example see QGeoShape and QGeoRectangle [here](https://github.com/qt/qtlocation/tree/dev/src/positioning)).

Solution above has some disadvantages when you need to use several classes inherited from `Shape` (For example `virtual Circle Shape::boundingCircle() const`) in `Shape` class declaration. Maybe someone know another solution?

Comment: You can, and you did, declare `Rectangle` before `Shape` in `Shape.h`. What is the problem?

Comment: @Quentin the problem is a compile time error. Forward declaring Rectangle is enough to pass it by reference or pointer, but if it's passed/returned by value then the compiler needs to know its size.

Comment: You can use forward declarations only as references or pointers.

Comment: @PeterT Incomplete types can be used as parameters and return values in declarations without issue, see [this demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1d631f91f3d9ceb).

Comment: Yes, correct, my mistake.